# Vue doesnt get changes from Firestore without refreshing

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to make a task tracker app in vue. I almost finished the project when i realized that when i add a task, it goes on the tasks view but when i try to change the reminder (it's a boolean and when i double click the task, it change the value) nothing happens until i reload the page. here is the code
Home.vue

```
<template>
  <AddTask v-show="showAddTask" @add-task="addTask" />
  <Tasks
    @toggle-reminder="toggleReminder"
    @delete-task="deleteTask"
    :tasks="tasks"
  />
</template>

<script>
import Tasks from '../components/Tasks'
import AddTask from '../components/AddTask'
import firebase from 'firebase'
import Login from './Login'
import Signup from './Signup'
export default {
  name: 'Home',
  props: {
    showAddTask: Boolean,
    
  },
  components: {
    Tasks,
    AddTask,
    Login,
    Signup,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      tasks: [],
      myiid:''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addTask(task) {
      this.tasks.push(task)
      firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
        if (user) {
          firebase
          .firestore()
          .collection(user.uid)
          .add(task).then((docRef) => {
            this.myiid = docRef.id
            firebase.firestore().collection(user.uid).doc(this.myiid).update({id: this.myiid})
            console.log(docRef.id)
            
          })
          
        }     
      })
      this.myiid = ''
    },
    deleteTask(id) {
      firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
        if (user) {
          if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {
            firebase.firestore().collection(user.uid).get().then((querySnapshot) =>{
              querySnapshot.forEach((doc)=> {
                if (doc.ref.id == firebase.firestore().collection(user.uid).doc(id).id) {
                  doc.ref.delete();
                }
              (this.tasks = this.tasks.filter((task) => task.id !== id))
            })
          })
      }
        }
      })
    },
    toggleReminder(id) {

      firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
        if (user) {
          firebase.firestore().collection(user.uid).get().then((documentSnapshot) =>{
            documentSnapshot.forEach((doc)=> {
              if (doc.data().id === id) {
                doc.ref.update({reminder: !doc.data().reminder })
                this.tasks = this.tasks.map((task) =>
                  task.id === id ? { ...task, reminder: !doc.data().reminder } : task)
              }
              })
          })
        }
     })
    },
    fetchTasks() {
      firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
        if (user) {
          var uid = user.uid
          firebase.firestore().collection(uid).get().then((querySnapshot) => {
            querySnapshot.forEach((doc)=>{
            this.tasks = [...this.tasks, doc.data()]
             })
          })
        }
      })
    }
  },
  async created() {
    this.fetchTasks()
  }
}
</script>
```

Here is the link for my app if you want to check it on your own

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `fetchTasks` function uses `get()` to read the data from Firestore, which means that it [reads data only once](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data). If you want to read the data once and continue to listen for [realtime updates](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen), you'll need to use `onSnapshot()` instead of `get()`

```
fetchTasks() {
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if (user) {
      var uid = user.uid
      firebase.firestore().collection(uid).onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
        this.tasks = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data());
      })
    }
  })
}
```